# MS flow delete file from file system

Tags: sharepoint-online, file, flow, delete, microsoft-flow

I have created a flow to delete file from file system but I am getting error as below screenshot:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot of the configurations you used for connection and also complete error you are getting? It is not clear from the attached screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, I add the “delete file” action in the flow and it can work fine.

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Check if the file which you want to delete exists in the file system.
2. Check if the connection is configured correctly.
3. Check if the data Gateways is installed and configured correctly.